# Always show the first axis label

Tags: python, plot, plotly

What I try to do is to have x axis that starts from 1 and has only integers.
My plot's x axis starts from one thanks to `this0` option and has integer values (`tickformat`) but depending on data axis labeling starts from first or second element.
And I have to always have this first label (which is always one) visible.

[image]

P.S. X axis data range is variable so tickmode should be auto.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotly - starting X axis from first data point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156590/plotly-starting-x-axis-from-first-data-point)

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I know about `dticks` but max x on axis can be from 10 to even 1000. Probably there's no other way than specifying all `tickvals` by myself. That's a pity.

Comment: Code would be nice.